# When is it safe to wrap in a conditional code requiring an assembly that may not be present?

Tags: c#, if-statement, .net-assembly

When, if ever, is it safe to wrap behind a conditional code that requires an assembly that may not be present?

For example:

```
if (SafeCheckForOptionalAssembly()) {
    // Code requiring an optional assembly
} else {
    // fallback: don't rely on optional assembly
}
```

Directly related questions:

1. Does it matter if the conditionally included code uses a type contained within the optional assembly? (e.g. `var foo = new MyClassInOptionalAssembly()`)
2. Does the behavior change if the conditionally included code is wrapped in a method?

Comment: I have put the code requiring optional assembly into a method. This way it worked in .NET 3.5 and 4. But I am not sure if this is guaranteed to not fail. The code failed if the said code was included directly.

Comment: that won't work - at least not in all cases/on all platforms... why not use an `interface`, include a default implementation, then check if the optional Assembly (implementing this interface) is present and if so instantiate from the Assembly otherwise use the default implementation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, doesn't work.  The jitter will bomb trying to *compile* the method before it starts running.  The exception is raised in the calling method.
2. Possibly.  But to be 100% sure, you'll need to apply the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] attribute so the method never gets inlined.

These assumptions are only valid for a jitter that compiles on demand.  The Microsoft x86 and x64 jitters do.  The Mono jitter doesn't (last I looked).

Comment: No guarantees, this is all highly implementation specific as the last sentence points out.